# how to install from bioconductor using install2.r from littler?

Tags: r, installation, littler

I'm trying to use https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/littler/vignettes/littler-examples.html#install2r:_With_Cmdline_Parsing to install some packages during which I get the error `dependency 'graph' is not available`. It appears that this package is available from Bioconductor project (https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/graph.html) but I don't know how to install it using `install2.r`.

So, specifically how can I install bioconductor packages using `install2.r`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't because BioConductor uses a different repository structure.

But because this is a frequent-enough problem, I recently added a helper script `installBioc.r` you use.  To use it, first do

```
 install.r littler BiocManager
```

to make sure we have the current `littler` release as well as the BioC package `BiocManager` we need.  Then use eg

```
  /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/littler/examples/installBioc.r S4Vectors
```

and it will go off and install `BiocVersion`, `S4Vectors` as well as 
the dependency `BiocGenerics`.

Comment: Thanks Dirk! One more question: since I'm aware that one of the packages depends on `graph` from Bioconductor I ought to run `installBioc.r graph` before running `install2.r <my pkgs here>`? Relatedly, is it possible that `install2.r` can suggest downloading the missing package from Bioconductor as a part of error/warning?  BTW, I really like using install2.r and rocker (mostly for geospatial related R work)! I cannot thank you enough for all that you do for the R community. I, personally, appreciate all of it!

Comment: Thanks for the kind words, and good question. I am a little fuzzy on this but now also have some containers needed BioC packages (hence the new helper). I tend to bring in from CRAN what I need but I _think_ as we call out to `BiocManager` it would bring whatever we need from CRAN too.  (And the old problem of system libraries is of course unsolved as the CRAN + BioC installers do not interact with `apt`, but I presume you knew that....)

Comment: Dealing with system libraries is a difficult problem...especially getting geospatial packages working _reliably_ in R...so I completely understand. Thank you.